# Security proof of the Schnorr Signature

Tags: cryptanalysis, signature, hash-signature, integrity, forgery

How Schnorr signature security can be proved for signature forgery, replacement, and Replay attacks?

Comment: Signatures are static, thus can be replayed. Are you thinking of the Schnorr identification protocol?

Comment: No, I am using Schnorr to sign a message m, and I want to make sure this signature can be replayed in case of a message update. i.e. sig(m) != sig(m').

Comment: http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/029.pdf

Comment: @polfosol thank you